# Best practices or the effective approach to write integration test which run in a continues integration environment

Tags: java, spring, continuous-integration, testng, integration-testing

In general, I write integration test from my service/ remoting layer to the database so that I can check the server side layers are integrated and tested, I would like to keep the rollback as false if not we will miss out the database constraint level validation. It is a personal preference.

We can follow different approaches
 - Create data for each test case and delete it once executed
 - Run with a certain amount of existing common data such as (User)

There may be entities depends on other several entities and to be able to test such flows it requires a lot of effort to create every entity for each test case or class and maybe for a business flow if we make a decision we create a certain amount of data and execute a business flow with a certain number of test and clear the data. These things can consume a lot of time to run such test cases.

Is there an effective approach or best practice that is followed in the industry to write integration test in the continues integration environments. I normally use TestNG as it provides spring support. Is there any Java-based frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on a project and there is no silver bullet solution here.

There are indeed many approaches as you state, I'll mention a few:

1. Take advantage of Spring's `@Transactional` annotation on the test. In this case, spring will execute rollback after each test. so that the data changed by the test won't really be saved in the database even if the test passes.
2. Do not use @Transactional but organize tests so that they won't interfere (each test will use its own set of data that can co-exist with other tests data). If the test fails and doesn't "clean-up" its stuff, then other tests should still run. In addition, if the tests are being run in parallel, they still should not interfere.
3. Use new schema for each test (obviously expensive, but still can be a viable option to some projects).

Now, the real question is what do you test. 
If you test a java code, like that your SQLs are created correctly, then probably the first way is a way to go.

Of course, it also depends on what commands are being executed during the tests, not in all databases all the commands can be in a transaction (for example in Postgres you can use DDL inside a transaction, in Oracle you can't, and so forth).

Another concern to think about during the continuous testing is the performance of tests.
Integration tests are slow and if you have a monolith application that runs hundreds of them, then the build will be really slow. Managing build that runs hours is a big pain.
I would like to mention here 2 ideas that can help here:

- Moving to microservices helps a lot in this case (each microservice runs only a bunch of its tests and hence the build of each microservice on its own is much faster by nature)
- Another interesting option to consider is running the tests against a docker container of the database that starts right in the test case (it also can be cached so that not every test will raise a docker container). A big benefit of such an approach is that everything runs locally (on the build server), so no interaction with the remote database (performance) + the clean-up of resources is done automatically, even if some tests fail. The Docker container dies and all the data put by the tets gets cleaned up automatically. Take a look at [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) project maybe you'll find it helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot, TestContainers sounds fantastic